On a complete metric field, does closed bounded subspaces have extrema (and contain them)?
Saying it otherwise, do such subspaces have the least-upper-bound property, which is useful in many analysis proofs? How can it be proved?
To be clearer:
let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field;
let $d:(x,y)\in \mathbb{K}\times \mathbb{K}\mapsto \mathbb{R^+}$ a metric on $\mathbb{K}$
let $V$ be a closed bounded subspace of $\mathbb{K}$ (closed and $\exists M\in\mathbb{R^+}:\forall(x,y)\in V\times V,d(x,y)\leq M$)
let $|.|:x\in\mathbb{K}\mapsto \mathbb{R^+}, |x|\hat{=}d(x,0)$
Does $sup_{x\in V}\{|x|\}$ exists and is reached by some $x_0\in V$?
(NB without closeness I would have say "exists and is reached in $\bar{V}$")
I just found that, for instance, an supremum exist by recursively building a sequence of elements of strictly increasing size, which is bounded, thus convergent on $\mathbb{R}^+$ but it's not a converging sequence of element of the subspace. I have not used the completness of a enclosing metric space either so far.

What is a (complete) metric field? Furthermore, it seems that they have an order, or what do you mean by "least-upper-bound property"?

@Ulli a field with a metric and which is complete for this metric. From this metric $d(x,y)$, I'm deriving a "magnitude" $d(x,0)$. I'm editing the question for clarification.

Didn't you want to assume completeness? What is "sup"? You need an order on the field! Don't you require any compatibility between the metric and the field structure?

@Ulli $|.|$ induces a partial ordering. fixing again the question wrt your comment.

No: consider $\mathbb K = V = (0,1)$ with the usual metric coming from $\mathbb R$, and an arbitrary field structure, where $0$ is the zero-element w.r.t. this field. Of course, $V$ is bounded and closed, but there is no $x_0 \in V$, such that $|x_0| = 1 = \text{sup} {|x|: x \in V}$. I'm sure that is not a counter-example, you had in mind. But if you don't require any compatibility between the metric and the field structure, it is a counter-example!

@Ulli, I don't follow. If I understand your notation as the set of two elements from $\mathbb{R}$ 0 and 1, then $x_0=1$ is OK?

@Ulli OK, thanks. So what property should I had to make the statement valid (you seemed to have some idea when you spoke about "compatibility"?)

No, $(0,1) = {x \in \mathbb R: 0 < x < 1}$ is the open interval in the reals. But, yes, sorry, the example should be  $\mathbb K = V = [0,1) = {x \in \mathbb R: 0 \le x < 1}$.

Well, perhaps you could consider absolute values. But I have the strong feeling that your whole question doesn't have to do so much with fields, but rather some compactness conditions on metric spaces. For instance, if $V$ is compact, non-empty, there exists such an $x_0$.

@Ulli Actually I'm reading about functional analysis, starting with metrics, completeness, compactness and so on. When I read the properties of finite dimensional spaces (among which the equivalence of norms) the proofs all relied on the underlying field being $\mathbb{R}$ and properties that came from its least-upper-bound property. I'm looking for more generic proofs (for fields that are neither  $\mathbb{R}$ nor  $\mathbb{C}$) and I'm searching what properties these fields must have for the "big" properties to hold (first of all norms equivalence).

@Ulli: Both bounded and complete is a rather strong condition, specially if you define bounded by $\exists x\in\Bbb K, \forall y \in V, \lvert y \rvert \le \lvert x\rvert$...

Anyway, $\Bbb K$ is declared to be a field with a metric. Is there any relation between the metric and the operators of the field? For example is $d(a,b) = d(0, b-a)$ required? If the metric is unrelated with the field operators, we could imagine that $\Bbb K$ is not connected which opens a large gate to find counter examples...

Even if the metric comes from a multiplicative absolute value, this should fail whenever $\mathbb{K}$ is not locally compact e.g. if $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{C}_p$.

@ShyamR. : I have stopped studying maths for a loooong time and I am not used to all the symbols. What is $\mathbb{C}_p$ please? That being said, I can remember that the unit ball is not compact for vector spaces having infinite dimensions...

@SergeBallesta $\mathbb{C}_p$ is the completion of the algebraic closure of the $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Unlike $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{C}_p$ is not locally compact so the closed unit ball ${x \in \mathbb{C}_p : |x| \leq 1}$ is not compact.

Yes, the supremum always exists. Fix any $v \in V$. Then for any $x \in V$, $|x| = d(0, x) \leq d(0, v) + d(x,v)$ by the tringle inequality, and $d(x,v) \leq M$ since $V$ is bounded. Thus the set $\{|x|\}$ is a bounded set of real numbers and so has a finite supremum.
No, the $|x|$ need not always attain the supremum. You have put no constraints on how the metric should behave based on the field operations, so you're pretty much just asking if the supremum of distances from a fixed point is always achieved in a closed complete bounded subset of a metric space. We'll use $\mathbb{R}$ to underscore that this can be done for a metric space that has a familiar field structure.
Let $C(x)$ be the ceiling function that rounds up to the next biggest integer, and consider the following metric on the interval $[0, \infty)$:
$$
c(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
|x-y|\frac{C(x)}{C(x) + 1} \text{, if } C(x) = C(y) \\
(x - C(x-1))\frac{C(x)}{C(x) + 1} + (y - C(y-1))\frac{C(y)}{C(y)+1} \text{ otherwise.} \\
\end{cases}
$$
Intuitively, this metric rips out each interval $(n, n+1]$ (for integer $n$) and glues the open end of it to zero, then shrinks down each one a bit so that their lengths approach 1. We'll now extend this to a metric on $\mathbb{R}$ by just "gluing on" the negative reals with the standard metric: consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the metric $d(x,y)$ defined as
$$
d(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
|x-y| \text{, if } x, y \leq 0\\
c(x,y) \text{, if } x, y \geq 0 \\
d(x,0) + c(y,0) \text{ otherwise. } \\
\end{cases}
$$
This metric doesn't induce the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, but again you did not stipulate that in your question.
Let $V = \mathbb{R}^+ \subset \mathbb{R}$, using $d$ as our metric. Clearly $V$ is bounded since everything is distance at most $1$ from $0$. I'll leave as an exercise to prove $V$ is complete - roughly, a Cauchy sequence must either approach $0$ or eventually stay within an interval $[n + \epsilon, n+1]$, whose metric is just a multiple of the standard metric on a real interval. We have $\sup_{x \in V}(|x|) = 1$, since, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $d(0,n)$ approaches 1 as $n$ approaches $\infty$, but there is no $x \in V$ such that $d(0, x) = 1$.

Thank you for your very detailed question. As you must have guessed, I'm not an expert  on these question and I don't know how to "patch" the metric wrt to the field (what hypothesis should I had) in order to get the desired least-upper-bound property)?

I believe the typical approach would to be to assert that $\mathbb{K}$ must be some sort of normed real vector space, and require the metric to be the one defined by the norm.
