$A\in L(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y}), \ker(A^*)=\{0\}\Rightarrow Ran(A)=\mathcal{Y}$
In Charles A. Micchelli and Massimiliano A. Pontil. 2005. On Learning Vector-Valued Functions. Neural Comput. 17, 1 (January 2005), 177–204, the authors design a linear, continuous application $A$ between two Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$.
They show that, under some condition $\ker(A^*)=\{0\}$.
They then use that $\ker(A^*)=Ran(A)^\perp$ to conclude that $\mathcal{Y}=Ran(A)$.
Yet, according to classical orthogonality theorems, $\mathcal{Y}={Ran(A)}^\perp\bigoplus\overline{Ran(A)}$.
Thus the author asumption is correct, only if $\overline{Ran(A)}=Ran(A)$, ie $Ran(A)$ is closed. Is it correct? How can I prove it?
Note: I found partial proofs showing that the graph of $A$ is closed.

This is generally not true. What is true is that $\ker A^*=(0)$  IFF $\overline{R(A)}=Y$. Do you have any other conditions?

@EvangelopoulosFoivos I may have oversimplified the problem. Here is a link to the original text. My question arises from the proof of lemma 1, in 3- minimal norm interpolation

My guess: A is linear thus Ran(A)=Span(A), a vector space. Then in finite dimension a vector space is closed, thus $\overline{Ran(A)}=Ran(A)$. Does it sound correct? For the record, can someone provide a counter-example in infinite dimensions?

hum, looking at my notes, my former comment si true on $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces. To extend to any $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces, with $\mathbb{K}$ a field, I'd need, for instance, that all norms are equivalent. Yet it's not obvious. (related to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4991793/1306116)
